# Problem extracting email address from a person-group column

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, email, person

I have "Person or Group" column in a custom list of a sharepoint online site. The users get pulled up fine when adding or editing the list item. In the SP 2013 workflow designer I am not able to get the email address out of this column. The only thing I get in return is blank in the Title column. What should I do to get the email address from a Person-Group column?

[image]

My final objective is to build a comma delimited string of unduplicated email addresses which can be sent email at the end of the workflow.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Do you see the email address in the configuration of the user, via UI?

Comment: The auto-complete allows me to select the staff name when I partially type in their name. When I hover mouse over their name in the selection list I do see their email address also.

Comment: Whatsup with the images. I do not see the screenshot I uploaded to the original post. Is it just me not being able to see it?

Comment: I can see it...

Comment: If you go a user's profile (in the browser, not in Designer), does their email address show up?

Comment: Yes it does. When I click on the name of the staff in the Person-Group column in the custom list, it takes me to the profile page where the email address is listed.

Comment: Where you have create item in test, this is supposed to return an integer as variable create. Have you tried a more basic test? Something like `Log [%Current List: Staff%] (as email address) where ID = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a newbie, I didn't know that I can get the email addresses directly through the REST call. What I was getting was the StaffId from the plain REST call I was making. I read up on some of the parameters like $expand and $select that could allow me to get to the person-group column details like email address, department, etc. This solved my issue.

Thanks for all the feedback!